# Can't boot ubuntu after intallation

Tags: boot, 20.04

After installing ubuntu in a clean disk it does not boot. I got the boot-info and shows this: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QfCCKM7KNJ/

After that I did boot repair and give another url:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QfCCKM7KNJ/

I did try to set the boot loader as the suggested one but when I tries to boot it shows in a black screen:

```
reboot and select proper boot device after installing ubuntu in a clean disk
```

Comment: It looks like Mint? Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu are supported here. Typically the Desktop installer did not support RAID, you had to use the Server installer. You also have weird RAID as one drive is gpt and one is MBR. RAID is two identical drives.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I downloaded ubuntu desktop from the official site. In the BIOS I had a section where it said RAID with a green light and in another menu shown AHCI. I did not realized of this second one. Once I changed It gave me the options to but from ubuntu and It worked. I
I made Ubuntu desktop work with RAID with the custom configuration setting the right boot loader.